# a plugin for individual wheel on a 4 wheel robot in gazebo? Ros2 (foxy)

Tags: ros2, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have a question. So, is there any single plugin that works with individual wheel on robot with 4 wheels?

I'm using Gazebo11 and Foxy (ros2).

As I'm aware that libgazebo_ros_diff_drive controls 2 wheels and libgazebo_ros_ackermann_drive controls 4 wheels. I wanted to have a plugin where I'm able to control a single wheel or run with all wheels individual. Do you know the name of the plugin? Any tutorial too?

Thank you so much for your time!

### Update 2

Here is my current launch file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch.substitutions import Command, FindExecutable, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch import LaunchDescription, LaunchContext
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import Command, FindExecutable, LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch.conditions import IfCondition, UnlessCondition
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
import launch_ros
import os
import sys
import launch_ros.actions
import xacro
import launch


def generate_launch_description():
    pkg_path = FindPackageShare("my_robot_description")

    use_sim = LaunchConfiguration("use_sim")
    use_fake_hardware = LaunchConfiguration("use_fake_hardware")
    fake_sensor_commands = LaunchConfiguration("fake_sensor_commands")

    xacro_path = PathJoinSubstitution([pkg_path, "urdf", "my_robot.urdf"])
    assert os.path.exists(xacro_path.perform(LaunchContext())), (
    "The xacro file doesn't exist (" + str(xacro_path.perform(LaunchContext())) + ")"
    )



    robot_description_content = Command(
    [
        PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
        " ",
        PathJoinSubstitution(
            [
                PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
                " ",
                xacro_path,
                " ",
                "use_sim:=",
                use_sim,
                " ",
                "use_fake_hardware:=",
                use_fake_hardware,
                " ",
                "fake_sensor_commands:=",
                fake_sensor_commands,

                FindPackageShare("my_robot_description"),
                "src/description",
                "my_robot.urdf",
            ]
        ),
    ]
    )

    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}

    controller_config_path = PathJoinSubstitution(
    [
        pkg_path,
        "config",
        "gazebo_ros_control_params.yaml",
    ]
    )
    assert os.path.exists(controller_config_path.perform(LaunchContext())), (
    "The controller config doesn't exist ("
    + str(controller_config_path.perform(LaunchContext()))
    + ")"
    )

    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}
    rviz_config_file = PathJoinSubstitution(
    [FindPackageShare("my_robot_description"), "rviz", "urdf_config.rviz"]
    )

    rviz_node = Node(
    package="rviz2",
    executable="rviz2",
    name="rviz2",
    output="log",
    arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file],
    )
    robot_state_pub_node = Node(
    package="robot_state_publisher",
    executable="robot_state_publisher",
    output="both",
    parameters=[robot_description],
    )
    spawn_entity = launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='gazebo_ros',
    executable='spawn_entity.py',
    arguments=['-entity', 'my_robot', '-topic', 'robot_description'],
    output='screen'
    )

    return launch.LaunchDescription([
    #
    # Launch Arguments
    #
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "use_sim",
        default_value="false",
        description="Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true",
    ),
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "use_fake_hardware",
        default_value="true",
        description="Start robot with fake hardware mirroring command to its states.",
    ),
    DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "fake_sensor_commands",
        default_value="false",
        description="Enable fake command interfaces for sensors used for simple simulations. \
                Used only if 'use_fake_hardware' parameter is true.",
    ),
    Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[robot_description, controller_config_path],
        output={
            "stdout": "screen",
            "stderr": "screen",
        },
        condition=UnlessCondition(use_sim),
    ),
    Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        output="both",
        parameters=[robot_description, {"use_sim_time": use_sim}],
    ),
    Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner.py",
        arguments=[
            "joint_state_broadcaster",
            "--controller-manager",
            "/controller_manager",
        ],
    ),
    Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner.py",
        arguments=["wheel_velocity_controller", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
    ),
    launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'], output='screen'),
    launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(
        name='fake_joint_calibration',
        cmd=['ros2', 'topic', 'pub', '/joint_states', 'sensor_msgs/msg/JointState', '"{data True}"'],
        output='screen',
        shell='True'
    ),

    robot_state_pub_node,
    rviz_node,
    spawn_entity,
    ])
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384190/a-plugin-for-individual-wheel-on-a-4-wheel-robot-in-gazebo?-ros2-(foxy)/) by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2021-08-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not really an expert on this and I myself struggled the last two weeks with ROS2, Gazebo and ROS2_Control, but I think you should be able to use ROS2_Control for that.

Here some useful links:

- ROS2 Control Documentation:
  https://ros-controls.github.io/control.ros.org/getting_started.html#
- ROS2 Control Demo:
  https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos
- Gazebo ROS2 Control Plugin:
  https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros2_control

You have to add a `ros2_control` tag to your URDF file. [(ref)](https://ros-controls.github.io/control.ros.org/getting_started.html#hardware-description-in-urdf). Mine looks like this:

```
  <!-- ROS Control for the rims -->
  <ros2_control name="cassiopeia_rim_control" type="system">
    <xacro:if value="$(arg use_sim)">
      <hardware>
        <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
      </hardware>
    </xacro:if>
    <xacro:unless value="$(arg use_sim)">
      <hardware>
        <xacro:if value="$(arg use_fake_hardware)">
          <plugin>fake_components/GenericSystem</plugin>
          <param name="fake_sensor_commands">$(arg fake_sensor_commands)</param>
          <param name="state_following_offset">0.0</param>
        </xacro:if>
        <xacro:unless value="$(arg use_fake_hardware)">
          <!-- TODO: If we want this feature, we have to write an
                     hardware controller plugin in C++ for ROS2 Control.
            -->
        </xacro:unless>
      </hardware>
    </xacro:unless>

    <joint name="a_rim_joint">
      <command_interface name="velocity">
        <param name="min">-1</param>
        <param name="max">1</param>
      </command_interface>
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="b_rim_joint">
      <command_interface name="velocity">
        <param name="min">-1</param>
        <param name="max">1</param>
      </command_interface>
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="c_rim_joint">
      <command_interface name="velocity">
        <param name="min">-1</param>
        <param name="max">1</param>
      </command_interface>
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    </joint>
  </ros2_control>

  <gazebo>
    <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
      <parameters>$(find pkg_name)/config/controllers.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

It is worth noting that, if you want to use ROS2 Control with gazebo, you have to use one `ros2_control` tag with type `system` for all joints. Additionally, the `xacro:if` in the beginning is if you want to use the same model in Gazebo and on the real robot. If you are only interested in Gazebo, just evaluate `use_sim` to `true`.

Then you'll also need the specified `controllers.yaml`. Here is mine:

```
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100  # Hz

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    wheel_velocity_controller:
      type: velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController


wheel_velocity_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - a_rim_joint
      - b_rim_joint
      - c_rim_joint

    command_interfaces:
      - velocity

    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
```

Here we have one controller for all three joints, that can be controlled with topic: `/wheel_velocity_controller/commands` of type: `Type: std_msgs/msg/Float64MultiArray`. If you want different topics for each joint, just define more controllers in the yaml file.

**Update 1:**
Here is my launch file:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription, LaunchContext
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import Command, FindExecutable, LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch.conditions import IfCondition, UnlessCondition
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

import os


def generate_launch_description():
    pkg_path = FindPackageShare("cassiopeia_description")

    use_sim = LaunchConfiguration("use_sim")
    use_fake_hardware = LaunchConfiguration("use_fake_hardware")
    fake_sensor_commands = LaunchConfiguration("fake_sensor_commands")

    xacro_path = PathJoinSubstitution([pkg_path, "urdf", "cassiopeia.urdf.xacro"])
    assert os.path.exists(xacro_path.perform(LaunchContext())), (
        "The xacro file doesn't exist (" + str(xacro_path.perform(LaunchContext())) + ")"
    )

    # Get URDF from Xacro
    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            xacro_path,
            " ",
            "use_sim:=",
            use_sim,
            " ",
            "use_fake_hardware:=",
            use_fake_hardware,
            " ",
            "fake_sensor_commands:=",
            fake_sensor_commands,
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}

    controller_config_path = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            pkg_path,
            "config",
            "controllers.yaml",
        ]
    )
    assert os.path.exists(controller_config_path.perform(LaunchContext())), (
        "The controller config doesn't exist ("
        + str(controller_config_path.perform(LaunchContext()))
        + ")"
    )

    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            #
            # Launch Arguments
            #
            DeclareLaunchArgument(
                "use_sim",
                default_value="false",
                description="Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true",
            ),
            DeclareLaunchArgument(
                "use_fake_hardware",
                default_value="true",
                description="Start robot with fake hardware mirroring command to its states.",
            ),
            DeclareLaunchArgument(
                "fake_sensor_commands",
                default_value="false",
                description="Enable fake command interfaces for sensors used for simple simulations. \
                Used only if 'use_fake_hardware' parameter is true.",
            ),
            #
            # Nodes
            #
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="ros2_control_node",
                parameters=[robot_description, controller_config_path],
                output={
                    "stdout": "screen",
                    "stderr": "screen",
                },
                condition=UnlessCondition(use_sim),
            ),
            Node(
                package="robot_state_publisher",
                executable="robot_state_publisher",
                output="both",
                parameters=[robot_description, {"use_sim_time": use_sim}],
            ),
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="spawner.py",
                arguments=[
                    "joint_state_broadcaster",
                    "--controller-manager",
                    "/controller_manager",
                ],
            ),
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="spawner.py",
                arguments=["wheel_velocity_controller", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
            ),
            #
            # Launch Files
            #
            IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                    [
                        PathJoinSubstitution(
                            [FindPackageShare("kamaro_gazebo"), "launch", "simulation.launch.py"]
                        )
                    ]
                ),
                launch_arguments={"verbose": "false"}.items(),
                condition=IfCondition(use_sim),
            ),
        ]
    )
```

Please note, that in `foxy` and below, you have to avoid `:` in your xml comments in the xacro file. See here: https://answers.ros.org/question/382000/ros2-makes-launch-files-crazy-too-soon-to-be-migrating/?answer=382141#post-id-382141

**Update 2:**
It's not surprising, that you have a lot of issues.
Here are some things that are don't make any sense.

1. How to read an URDF/Xacro file into an param to give it to the `robot_state_publisher`

> ```
> robot_description_content = Command(
>     [
>         PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
>         " ",
>         PathJoinSubstitution(
>             [
>                 PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
>                 " ",
>                 xacro_path,
>                 " ",
>                 "use_sim:=",
>                 use_sim,
>                 " ",
>                 "use_fake_hardware:=",
>                 use_fake_hardware,
>                 " ",
>                 "fake_sensor_commands:=",
>                 fake_sensor_commands,
>
>                 FindPackageShare("my_robot_description"),
>                 "src/description",
>                 "my_robot.urdf",
>             ]
>         ),
>     ]
> )
> ```

Here is what you are doing. `run /path/to/xacro path/to/xacro path/to/model.urdf.xacro arg1:=a arg2:=b arg3:=c /path/to/robot_desc/src/desc/my_robot.urdf`
Xacro is an command which takes a path to an xacro file und returns an urdf file. You can run `xacro --help` to see this.

Here is what you should do: `run xacro /file/to/model.urdf.xacro arg1:=a`. The arg part is only needed if you pass arguments to your xacro file. I'll make an example later.
You can also think of `PathJoinSubstitution` as `os.path.join`. The only thing it does, is evaluating the params a bit later.
For now, here is how this launch looks like:

```
robot_description_content = Command(
    [
        PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
        " ",
        xacro_path,
        " ",
        "use_sim:=",
        use_sim,
        " ",
        "use_fake_hardware:=",
        use_fake_hardware,
        " ",
        "fake_sensor_commands:=",
        fake_sensor_commands,
    ]
)
```

In the end, this will make a call like this: `/opt/ros/foxy/bin/xacro ~/ws/install/robot_description/share/robot_description/urdf/robot.urdf.xacro use_sim:=false use_fake_hardware:=true fake_sensor_commands:=false`

And as I sayed, you only need those arguments at the end, if you use them in your xacro file. Here is how you do this:

In your `robot.urdf.xacro` file:

```
<!-- Enable setting arguments from the launch file -->
<xacro:arg name="param1" default="true" />
<xacro:arg name="param2" default="1337" />

<!-- Use xacro params as if-else -->
<xacro:if value="$(arg use_sim)">
  Test
</xacro:if>
<param name="name">$(arg param2)</param>
```

You can always debug your xacro file with the command `xacro path/to/robot.urdf.xacro`.

2. `robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}` is there twice.
3. I gave up and created a launch file, that does anything I think you'll need. Read through the ros2 control demos and other questions here. The Xacro params I use, like `use_sim` are for making the `robot_description` usable on the real robot as well as in gazebo. For what I understand, you only need the Gazebo capability. So don't forget your `<ros2_control name="..." type="system">` tag in your xacro file, as well as, this gazebo tag:

   $(find cassiopeia_description)/config/controllers.yaml

And here is your launch file:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription, LaunchContext
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import Command, FindExecutable, LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from launch_ros.actions import Node

import os


def generate_launch_description():
    pkg_path = FindPackageShare("my_robot_description")

    # Check if xacro file does exist
    xacro_path = PathJoinSubstitution([pkg_path, "urdf", "my_robot.urdf"])
    assert os.path.exists(xacro_path.perform(LaunchContext())), (
        "The xacro file doesn't exist (" + str(xacro_path.perform(LaunchContext())) + ")"
    )

    # Create robot_description
    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            xacro_path,
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}

    # Check if controller config does exist
    controller_config_path = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            pkg_path,
            "config",
            "gazebo_ros_control_params.yaml",
        ]
    )
    assert os.path.exists(controller_config_path.perform(LaunchContext())), (
        "The controller config doesn't exist ("
        + str(controller_config_path.perform(LaunchContext()))
        + ")"
    )

    # Check if rviz file does exist
    rviz_config_file = PathJoinSubstitution([pkg_path, "rviz", "urdf_config.rviz"])
    assert os.path.exists(rviz_config_file.perform(LaunchContext())), (
        "The controller config doesn't exist ("
        + str(rviz_config_file.perform(LaunchContext()))
        + ")"
    )

    # Launch configuration variables specific to simulation
    gui = LaunchConfiguration("gui")
    world = LaunchConfiguration("world")

    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            # Launch arguments used for gazebo
            DeclareLaunchArgument(
                "gui", default_value="True", description="Whether to execute gzclient"
            ),
            DeclareLaunchArgument(
                "world",
                default_value=PathJoinSubstitution([pkg_path, "worlds", "willowgarage.world"]),
                description="Full path to world model file to load",
            ),
            # Launch gazebo server and client
            IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                    [
                        PathJoinSubstitution(
                            [FindPackageShare("gazebo_ros"), "launch", "gzserver.launch.py"]
                        )
                    ]
                ),
                launch_arguments={"verbose": "true", "world": world}.items(),
            ),
            IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                    [
                        PathJoinSubstitution(
                            [FindPackageShare("gazebo_ros"), "launch", "gzclient.launch.py"]
                        )
                    ]
                ),
                condition=IfCondition(gui),
            ),
            # Launch rviz
            Node(
                package="rviz2",
                executable="rviz2",
                name="rviz2",
                output="log",
                arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file],
            ),
            # Launch robot state publisher
            Node(
                package="robot_state_publisher",
                executable="robot_state_publisher",
                output="both",
                parameters=[robot_description],
            ),
            # Spawn the robot in gazebo from the robot_description provided by robot_state_publisher
            Node(
                package="gazebo_ros",
                executable="spawn_entity.py",
                arguments=["-topic", "robot_description", "-entity", "robot"],
                output="screen",
            ),
            # Spawn joint_state_broadcaster
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="spawner.py",
                arguments=[
                    "joint_state_broadcaster",
                    "--controller-manager",
                    "/controller_manager",
                ],
            ),
            # Spawn custom controller
            # YOU PROBABLY NEED TO MODIFY THIS AND ADD ONE OF THOSE FOR EACH CONTROLLER
            # IN YOUR controller_config_path
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="spawner.py",
                arguments=["wheel_velocity_controller", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
            ),
        ]
    )
```

---

Originally posted by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) with karma: 100 on 2021-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2021-08-24**:
what does your launch look like?

Because I get the error output like this

```
[wheel_velocity_controller-2] The passed value needs to be a dictionary in YAML format
[ERROR] [wheel_velocity_controller-2]: process has died [pid 1009427, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 topic pub /joint_states sensor_msgs/msg/JointState "{data: True}"']
```

in my launch, it is:

```
return launch.LaunchDescription([
    launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'], output='screen'),
    launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(
        name='wheel_velocity_controller',
        cmd = ['ros2', 'topic', 'pub', '/joint_states', 'sensor_msgs/msg/JointState', '"{data: True}"'],
        output = 'screen',
        shell='True'
  ),
```

**Comment by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on 2021-08-24**:
I updated my answer with the launch file, because it is no big for a comment. (`Update 1`)

**Comment by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on 2021-08-24**:
You can use urdf only, but I would advice to use it, if you want to do more then just a small demo.

**Comment by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on 2021-08-24**:
I would advice to look at the ROS2 Control Demo pkg, that I linked above. Mine is basically a copy pasta of that and other examples/tutorials. Unfortunately, the ROS2 Documentation of most packages (even of the core packages, like ros_launch) are absolute garbage right now.

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2021-08-24**:
I followed your launch and I'm having a lot of issues now. I will take  a break then resume on this one.

I merged my launch with the launch you provide. I updated my launch in my post as well

**Comment by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on 2021-08-24**:
I added Update 2 and I think thats all I can give you. If you have smaller questions regarding this, open a new question. My answer is already too long and not fun to edit.

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2021-08-24**:
Thank you so much!!!

I end up have a last question after trying to fix this issue for almost 2 hours now lol I'm going to make a new question! I'm going to mark your question as an answer since it answers the question!

I wish I could cashapp you to donate u 50 dollars! haha

**Comment by [Darkproduct](https://answers.ros.org/users/52476/darkproduct/) on 2021-08-25**:
I'm glad I could help. I know the ROS2 Documentation is lacking and many packages don't even provide one.